# Prebuilding a "heavy" component?

Tags: performance, react-native, components

I've got a component, a custom keyboard, that takes about 1 second to show/build in React Native.

Is it possible to prebuild this component, say on start up, and have it appear instantly when I need to show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that is to render it ahead of time. You can easily do this by rendering with zero opacity or translateX out of screen, and make it visible by changing those properties.

Example:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    invisible: {
        opacity: 0,
        transform: [
            {translateX: -3000}
        ]
    }
})

const MyHeavyComponent = ({isVisible, ...props}) => {
    const visiblityStyle = isVisible ? null : styles.invisible;

    return (
        <View style={visiblityStyle}>
            ...
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will definitely be doing that.